# Google earth plugin alternatives for Linux

Tags: linux, api, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I want to show a Google Earth like globe on my website, where people can rotate it and zoom it like normal Google Earth. I want to show signed up users on my website on this glob but the problem I am facing is that Google Earth plug in is not available for Linux , what other options do I have? thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "other options". As you correctly state the plug-in doesn't work on Linux so there isn't any other option as far as that goes.

At Google I/O back in May 2008 it was announced that the plug-in would be available for both Mac and Linux by August that year - however only the Mac version ever surfaced.

The last I heard on this was in 2011 on the feature request page for the plug-in.

> "...please note that we do believe that we can support Linux in the
>   future, and furthermore, we intend to support it. However currently we
>   do not have any timeline to announce for such a release."

See: https://code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/issues/detail?id=117

If you 'star' the request you should be notified of any updates, but as you can see it doesn't look to be something that is going to happen in any kind of hurry...

EDIT:

As for other, non-Google, alternatives you should take a look at [WebGL Earth](http://www.webglearth.org/) - it is still BETA but works on linux and is open source

Comment: The original post said `what options` not `what other options`, the edit may have slightly changed the meaning. I took it to mean something like if there are other options for this feature than using Google earth.

Comment: Ah ok, in any case I'm sorry I don't think there are any other 3d globe apis at all, bing maps used to have something but afaik it was pulled.