# Google earth api on linux?

Tags: linux, google-api, virtual-machine, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I would like to write in google api but I work with linux. AFAIK google earth plugin is not supported under linux.
Due to the issue in [Google Earth Plugin will not load under Windows 7 in Oracle Virtual Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861022/google-earth-plugin-will-not-load-under-windows-7-in-oracle-virtual-box) I'm not able to run windows on VM. Is there any other sollution for this issue ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google earth plugin alternatives for Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418138/google-earth-plugin-alternatives-for-linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still does not know why it not worked previously but now its is ok. It was about my enviroment.
Not worked on: `host ubuntu 12.04 lts_x64, virtualizing (vbox 4.1) x64 windows 7`

actually I made new machine and plugin works properly.
Works on: the same `host ubuntu 12.04 lts_x64, virtualizing (vbox 4.3) x64 windows 8.1.`

Firefox/chrome for both.